XeTeX Compilation Error: “missing hyphenation file” when setting lang: it in Quarto YAML
I’m working on a Quarto project and trying to generate a PDF using XeTeX with the document language set to Italian. Here’s the YAML header of my .qmd file:
---
title: Test
lang: it
format:
  pdf:
    toc: true
    number-sections: true
---
## Test

When I render the document, I receive the following error:
Rendering PDF
running xelatex - 1
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  
> 1 package to install
> installing hyphen-italian (1 of 1)
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  
ERROR: 
compilation failed- missing hyphenation file
see test.log for more information.

Interestingly, if I change the language to French (lang: fr), the problem disappears, and the PDF renders without issue.
I suspect this is related to a missing hyphenation file for Italian, but I’m unsure how to resolve it. tlmgr is not installed on my system, so I’m looking for alternative solutions or insights into this issue.
Additional Details:
I checked the test.log file, and it seems to indicate that the issue is related to missing hyphenation rules for the Italian language:
Package babel Info: Importing data for italian
(babel)             from babel-it.ini. Reported on input line 143.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'italian' set to \l@nil
(babel)             (\language7). Reported on input line 143.

It seems the hyphenation rules are not being properly set for Italian. This might be the root of the error. How can I ensure that the Italian hyphenation patterns are correctly installed and recognized by XeTeX?
How can I successfully render my document with lang: it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

about xelatex: https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project

How did you install texlive?

I've never installed texlive. xelatex (XeTeX) is part of tinytex a Quarto's tool. I've tried to change pdf-engine, using lualatex instead of xelatex and everything works. I've found the info here: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-engine.html

If you install texlive yourself, you can choose a full installation and never have again have problems with missing packages.
